# Proving that $\int_0^{\pi/2} |\exp(ire^{it})|dt < \pi /2r$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $r >0$. I want to prove that $\int_0^{\pi/2} |\exp(ire^{it})|dt < \pi /2r$ for $t \in [0, \pi/2]$. The hint is to use that $\sin t \ge 2t/\pi$ for $t \in [0, \pi/2]$. I really don't know what to use or how to start the proof, I've been trying to use that $|\int f| \le \int |f|$, putting it like $- \int |f| \le \int f \le \int |f|$, but I don't get an upper bound for $\int |f|$. I think this is the only result that I know which involves $\int |f|$ and inequalities. Any hints of which results I can use to prove this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first I thought this question was going to be a joke because the integrand spells out 'expired.'

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, how about $\int_0^{\pi/2} |\exp(ire^{d i})|\mathrm{d}d < \pi /2r$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\| e^z\|=e^{\Re(z)}$, your integral equals:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-r \sin t}dt\leq \int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-2rt/\pi}dt\leq\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-2rt/\pi}dt=\frac{\pi}{2r},$$
as wanted.

Notice that a more careful estimation is given by:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-r \sin t}dt\leq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{1+r\sin t}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\, dt}{t^2+2rt+1}\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\,dt}{2rt+1}=\frac{\log(2r+1)}{r}.$$